# remove all duplicates words from a given sentence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

Take the following string as an example:

```
var string = "All is well if it ends well";
```

From this string I would like to find the duplicate words, remove all the duplicates keeping one occurrence of the word in place and then output the revised string and also Reverse.

Which in this example would be:

```
var string = "ends it if is All"
```

Comment: Sure thing, seems like a very simple problem to solve with JavaScript. What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: This basically seems like a homework dump

Answer (score 0):

I would turn the string to an array, then remove duplicate, and then I would re-build the string.

Like so :

```
const string = 'All is well if it ends well';
const strToArr = string.split(' ');
const uniqueElementArr = Array.from(new Set(strToArr));
const newStr = uniqueElementArr.toString().replaceAll(',', ' ');

console.log(newStr) // outputs 'All is well if it ends'
```

I guess one could make it shorter